# Where are selected ringtone configuration is stored?

Tags: settings, system

I would like to know where the selected ringtone and notification sound is stored. I know that the ringtone files are stored in  */system/media/audio/*. What I'm trying to figure out is where the **current configuration** (user selected in  *Settings > Sound* ) is stored.

Thanks.

Comment: Try finding out what /data/data/com.android.providers.settings is keeping. Which  Android device and version are you using?

Comment: Sony Xperia ZL, 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noted in Android 5.1.1 and 5.0.2 (both from CM builds) and 4.2.1 that detail about user configured ringtone and notification sounds is stored in the table *system* of a database of Settings Providers/Storage app, */data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db*. In Android 6.0.1, the location is */data/system/users/0/settings_system.xml* or a relative one in an encrypted device.

You can use *content* tool to see it yourself. You would need [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) setup in PC to get the detail easily. Here's what you can try:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

**Note**: the lines starting with *echo* are for the purpose of explaining what I'm doing with the consecutive command. Avoid executing them when testing this solution.